# how to find first col value by maxium values in second col (in a matrix)

Tags: r

I have this matrix which I'm trying to find the `firstPlace` value by the maximum value/values in the `freq` column :

[image]

this is the code i use to get maxiumum values :

```
mat1[which(mat1 == max(mat1[,2]), arr.ind = TRUE)]
```

output:

[image]

But what I actually need is a `Vector` of `"CR","MS"`

EDIT:

this code which generate the matrix:

```
firstPlace <- c(1:100)
secondPlace <- c(1:100)
thirdPlace <- c(1:100)
for(i in thirdPlace){
  players <- c("CR","MS","LM")
  chances <- c(0.3,0.3,0.4)
  firstPlace[i] <- sample(players,size = 1,replace = TRUE ,prob = chances)
  players <- players[!(players %in% firstPlace[i])]
  secondPlace[i] <- sample(players,1,replace = TRUE)
  thirdPlace[i] <- players[!(players %in% secondPlace[i])]
  players <- c("CR","MS","LM")
}
mat1 <- as.data.frame(table(firstPlace)) %>% print()
```

Comment: Share you data with dput() and paste the output in here instead of using images.

Comment: its random outputs, you wont get the same as the image, i'll try any way

Comment: Then you can use set.seed() so output is reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `which.max` function which returns the index of the max element.

The code is as below:

```
as.character(mat1$firstPlace[which.max(mat1$Freq)])
```

P.S. This returns only the first maxima in case of two data points with maximum value. If you want all, I would suggest using the following:

```
as.character(mat1$firstPlace[which(mat1$Freq == max(mat1$Freq,na.rm=T))])
```

This should give you the desired output.

Comment: Almost... it returns CR and MS but not as a char vector. Instead its Factor w/3.
But Char Vector is require

Comment: @Omri you can simply add a ```as.character``` to convert it to character vector. I have edited the answer accordingly.